# Implementing PSHostRawUserInterface in F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to implement the sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706570(v=vs.85).aspx) with F# and cannot figure out how to correctly override the two overloads "SetBufferContents" in PSHostRawUserInterface:

```
#r "System.Management.Automation"

open System
open System.Management.Automation.Host

type MyRawUserInterface() =
    inherit PSHostRawUserInterface()
    override this.BackgroundColor with get() = Console.BackgroundColor and set v = Console.BackgroundColor <- v
    override this.BufferSize with get() = Size(Console.BufferWidth, Console.BufferHeight) and set v = Console.SetBufferSize(v.Width, v.Height)
    override this.CursorPosition with get() = raise (NotImplementedException()) and set _ = raise (NotImplementedException())
    override this.CursorSize with get() = Console.CursorSize and set v = Console.CursorSize <- v
    override this.ForegroundColor with get() = Console.ForegroundColor and set v = Console.ForegroundColor <- v
    override this.KeyAvailable with get() = Console.KeyAvailable
    override this.MaxPhysicalWindowSize with get() = Size(Console.LargestWindowWidth, Console.LargestWindowHeight)
    override this.MaxWindowSize with get() = Size(Console.LargestWindowWidth, Console.LargestWindowHeight)
    override this.WindowPosition with get() = Coordinates(Console.WindowLeft, Console.WindowTop) and set v = Console.SetWindowPosition(v.X, v.Y) 
    override this.WindowSize with get() = Size(Console.WindowWidth, Console.WindowHeight) and set v = Console.SetWindowSize(v.Width, v.Height)
    override this.WindowTitle with get() = Console.Title and set v = Console.Title <- v
    override this.FlushInputBuffer() = ()
    override this.GetBufferContents(_) = raise (NotImplementedException())
    override this.ReadKey(_) = raise (NotImplementedException())
    override this.ScrollBufferContents(_, _, _, _) = raise (NotImplementedException())
    override this.SetBufferContents(origin:Coordinates, contents:BufferCell[,]) = raise (NotImplementedException())
    override this.SetBufferContents(rectangle:Rectangle, fill:BufferCell) = raise (NotImplementedException())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a return type for the function as `raise` doesn't have a proper return type (it throws an exception).

This is what it should look like

```
override this.SetBufferContents(origin:Coordinates, contents:BufferCell[,]) : unit = raise (NotImplementedException())
```